# Problem with my batch script

Tags: batch-file

The donet installs like its suppose to but vcredist_x86.exe, and vs_piaredist.exe. Do you see anything that I am doing wrong? I want this to be a silent install.

```
 vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /c:"VCREDI~3.EXE /q:a /c""msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qu"""
 pause
 vs_piaredist.exe /q:a /c:"msiexe /i vs_2005_PIA.msi /qn"
 pause
 dotnetfx.exe /q:a /c:"install /l/q"
 pause
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem? For example, is it installing but not silently? Or is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I can see only two possible issues, if the script is copied without any changes/typos:

1. Line #1, `:` is probably missing after the second (inner) `/c` switch.
2. Line #3, `msiexe` should probably be `msiexec`.